# I-Report 4.1.1 static text element issue

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Hello everyone,
               I am using static text element in my column band.In that element i have aligned my text vertically in center of the element.I need the same alignment in the excel file when i am exporting the jrxml file.But i am getting  the default horizontal alignment ..Please provide me with the solution

Answer (score 2):

You can try this sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test_excel_columns" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, STREET, CITY FROM ADDRESS]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="FIRSTNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LASTNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="STREET" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="75" height="35"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="75" y="0" width="271" height="35"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="346" y="0" width="100" height="35"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Street]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="446" y="0" width="100" height="35"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[City]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="75" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="75" y="0" width="271" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FIRSTNAME} + " " + $F{LASTNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="346" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{STREET}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="446" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The output in Excel preview is:

[image]

My **`iReport`** version is `4.1.3`.

Comment: I have already added this textAlignment and verticalAlignment in my textelement but its not working

Comment: Did you check export function in iReport (via preview function)?

Comment: Ya i did,the preview window show me the required output in desired  format but during exportin into excel the output changes....

Comment: I am going to use java code for exporting in future but right now I am exporting the file from Ireports 4.1.1 to create the required template